# Google Analytics Screen Time Incorrect when using Measurement Protocol

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am using the measurement protocol for my Tizen TV application since I cannot use the JS (requires a domain name) nor Android/iOS SDKs.

I am sending

```
{
        v: 1,
        tid: GA_TRACKING_ID,
        cid: data.deviceId,
        t: 'screenview',
        dh: 'something.com',
        dp: encodeURIComponent($location.path()),
        cd: transition.to().title + ($stateParams.gaTitle ? ' (' + $stateParams.gaTitle + ')' : '') || 'Unknown',
        an: 'XXX',
        'ga:mobileDeviceModel': data.deviceModel
}
```

To `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect`

But the screen times seem off its always in the seconds eg. 30s etc. I tested staying on page for a long time but it does not seem correctly reflected. I guess its because I only send this hit once and theres no way for Google to know when it stopped? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you add a bit more insight on the problem you are facing like how you are _sending_ and what (in which approach) are you expecting back. More relevant code can be helpful.

Comment: Updated my OP. But basically I am making an API call to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to decide on the session timeout (Admin->property->tracking.js)
the default of 30 minutes means you will need to generate hits at intervals bellow 30 minutes to prevent new hits from being in a new session.

Then you need to make sure hits are frequent enough and include their current page/screen names, for example:

```
{ // start video
        v: 1,
        tid: GA_TRACKING_ID,
        cid: data.deviceId,
        t: 'screenview',
        dh: 'something.com',
        dp: encodeURIComponent($location.path()),
        cd: transition.to().title + ($stateParams.gaTitle ? ' (' + $stateParams.gaTitle + ')' : '') || 'Unknown',
        an: 'XXX',
        'ga:mobileDeviceModel': data.deviceModel
}
{ // < 30 minutes later
        v: 1,
        tid: GA_TRACKING_ID,
        cid: data.deviceId,
        t: 'event',
        ec: 'Inactivity',
        ea: 'Watching Video',
        el: ..video name..,
        ev: 28,
        ni: 0,  // count as interaction, ni=1 are ignored in time calculations 
        dh: 'something.com',
        dp: encodeURIComponent($location.path()),
        cd: transition.to().title + ($stateParams.gaTitle ? ' (' + $stateParams.gaTitle + ')' : '') || 'Unknown',
        an: 'XXX',
        'ga:mobileDeviceModel': data.deviceModel
}
{  // user does something (can wait 30 minutes more before a new ni event)
        v: 1,
        tid: GA_TRACKING_ID,
        cid: data.deviceId,
        t: 'event',
        ec: 'Activity',
        ea: 'Volume Adjustment Down',
        el: ..video name..,
        ev: 5,
        ni: 0,
        dh: 'something.com',
        dp: encodeURIComponent($location.path()),
        cd: transition.to().title + ($stateParams.gaTitle ? ' (' + $stateParams.gaTitle + ')' : '') || 'Unknown',
        an: 'XXX',
        'ga:mobileDeviceModel': data.deviceModel
}
{  // user goes to new screen (also calculated as the end of screen time)
        v: 1,
        tid: GA_TRACKING_ID,
        cid: data.deviceId,
        t: 'screenview',
        dh: 'something.com',
        dp: encodeURIComponent($location.path()),
        cd: 'somewhere else',
        an: 'XXX',
        'ga:mobileDeviceModel': data.deviceModel
}
```

If you have the ability to send on all exit events then you may want to use [queue time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt) on exit (or every 4 hours) to calculate for the session after all the data for the period is in.

Comment: Awesome, I will try this tomorrow. But I have a question. Shouldn't I at least have an average session time of ~30mins then? Why might my session time all so low?

Comment: @JiewMeng your session time is from the first hit to the last hit, where any gap of 30 minutes breaks the session, so if you navigate 2 minutes, then stay for 40 minutes somewhere, then go somewhere else you have one session of a few hits and two minutes and one 38 minutes later of 1 hit and 0 seconds. But you must also be careful to keep the cd/dp/dh parameters the same if you generate other hit types while wanting the session to appear to 'stay' on the same screen/page.

Comment: @JiewMeng you can also test on the hit builder https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ Either way, if you use 'qt' you can make 4 hrs of a user's virtual session(s) all at once for one cid then review them in reports->audience->user explorer.

Answer (score 3):

Google Analytics' session calculating is based on interaction from the user. If the user clicks, the session gets a heartbeat. If the user is watching a movie (TV e.g.) it wont be interacting with your application and the **session stops**

Take a look at this page
https://www.optimizesmart.com/understanding-sessions-in-google-analytics/